# Saving GProlog database

Tags: prolog, gnu-prolog

In my program I have a dynamic clauses, they works fine, but when I closing my program, they are disappears.

I've tryed that

```
saveState :-
  write_pl_state_file('backup.dat').

loadState :-
  file_exists('backup.dat'),
  read_pl_state_file('backup.dat'); !.
```

but this is not works.

Is there a way to save this databse to a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The predicates **write_pl_state_file/1** and **read_pl_state_file/1** are connected with the information/state that affects parsing of terms, i.e. operator definitions, character conversion Prolog flags, etc.

So that is part of your solution (perhaps), but more fundamentally you wish to save the dynamic clause definitions, probably in a form that allows you to reinstate them by consulting a file.

The predicate **listing/0** does something like this, but it displays the dynamic clauses to the "console", not to a file.  Probably you want to use [the underlying predicate](http://www.gprolog.org/manual/gprolog.html#portray-clause/2) **portray_clause/2**, which does allow redirecting output to a file (stream).

The author Daniel Diaz [noted a slight change](http://old.nabble.com/GNU-Prolog-1.4.0-is-released-td31955811.html) (adding a newline to end of output) for **portray_clause/2** in recent release notes for version 1.4.0, so you may want to make sure you've got the latest version for the sake of legibility.

**Added:**

It appears that starting with version 1.3.2 GNU Prolog supports sending **listing/0** output to the current stream (rather than just to the console as in 1.3.1 and earlier).

Here's a test case:

```
| ?- assertz(whoami(i)).
| ?- assertz(whoami(me)).
| ?- assertz(whoami(myself)).
```

which creates three clauses (facts) for a dynamic predicate **whoami/1**.

I then created a file myClauses.pl with the following query:

```
| ?- open('myClauses.pl',write,S), set_output(S), listing, close(S).
```

Once the stream S is closed, current output is reset to the console.

You will find that the file myClauses.pl contains a blank line followed by the three clauses, so that the source code is in proper form to be consulted.  However I'm having a problem with the **consult/1** predicate (and its File -> Consult... menu equivalent) in my newly installed GNU Prolog 1.4.0 under Windows.  The compilation works from the command line and produces a byte-code file that **load/1** can correctly handle in the console, so there's some small problem in how things are set up.  I'll post a further note when I get that squared away, having sent in a bug report.  I've not tried it yet under Linux.

Comment: SO can can I load this clauses with *consult*?

Comment: And can you provide some examples for saving?

Comment: @skayred: It does create a normal Prolog source file (without comments, of course, and with a bit of reconstruction on variable names).  I added a snippet above to illustrate the idea, although I ran into a problem with consulting files generally.  I'll post a further note when I get that figured out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`current_predicate/1`](http://www.gprolog.org/manual/gprolog.html#htoc106) or [`predicate_property/2`](http://www.gprolog.org/manual/gprolog.html#htoc107) to access predicates, and [`clause/2`](http://www.gprolog.org/manual/gprolog.html#htoc107) to access the clauses for a predicate.

Then you can write a save utility by using that information.